# enabling auto reload for askubuntu main questions page

Tags: feature-request

I am a regular at askubuntu and tend to gloss over all the questions. Is there a way to enable auto reload on the main questions page so that new questions can be seen without refreshing the page. If not is there a greasemonkey script which can do this for me?

Comment: Would you consider this to be [tag:status-completed] now that (a) you are notified when new questions appear, and (b) you can click that notification to load *only* the new questions, without refreshing the entire page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Firefox there is an extension that does just this: [ReloadEvery Mozilla Firefox Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/115/) However, I've found that pressing F5 is a good way to reload the page as I browse through the site. With this I'm able to know what question was last at the "top" and judge how many were added since I last checked.

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/refresh-on-the-frontpage) on MSO should give you some information on browser tools to do this.